# Doctrine Group by month DQL

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, group-by, dql

I have a problem that may be able to help me. I need to do a GROUP BY per month for a date in a DQL query. I saw that with Doctrine Extension can be done but I need to MySQL and Postgres. The idea is to count the number of times that a given parameter is repeated in a month. I fix currently doing one query per month, but this is not optimal , I need to do a single query that returns and grouped .
Thanks in advance and greetings

Comment: Can't you use GROUP By ?

Answer (score 0):

No, the problem is with MONTH, the DQL consult would be on this way:
SELECT count(s) FROM TestBundle:Entity s GROUP BY MONTH(s.date)
The MONTH function does no exist in DQL for Postgres, another alternative??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what DQL means, but in PostgreSQL you can group by a month in the following manner:

```
select
  extract (year from your_date) || '-' ||
  extract (month from your_date), count (*)
from your_table
where your_parameter = <whatever>
group by
  extract (year from your_date), extract (month from your_date)
```

Or my personal favorite:

```
select date_trunc ('month', your_date)::date, count (*)
from your_table
where your_parameter = <whatever>
group by date_trunc ('month', your_date)
```